# Harvard agsm bibliography style no comma and bold volume

Tags: bibliographies

I've been grappling with the harvard style bibliography (agsm) all day and have managed to fix most of the issues I've had, however I am still left with bold volume numbers and no comma between the journal and volume.

What I have at the moment is this:

> Whipple, K. & Tucker, G. (2002), Implications of sediment-flux-dependent river incision models for landscape evolution, Journal of Geophysical Research **107**(B2), 2039.

The 107 after the journal name is bold and there is no comma separating them.

What I need is

> Whipple, K. & Tucker, G. (2002), Implications of sediment-flux-dependent river incision models for landscape evolution, Journal of Geophysical Research, 107(B2), 2039.

Comma inserted between the journal and volume and the bold changed to normal font for the volume number of 107.

Which line of the bst file in the agsm bib style would control this? And what should I change it with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve the issue with volumes being bold faced, edit your copy of `agsm.bst` in the following way: inside the function

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
```

look for the line

```
{ volume embolden field.or.null
```

and delete `embolden`; i.e., replace the above line with

```
{ volume field.or.null
```

Now, to add the comma, inside the function

```
FUNCTION {article}
```

search for the lines

```
{ journal emphasize "journal" duplicate$ item.check
  " " * format.vol.num.pages * output
}
```

and replace them with

```
{ journal emphasize "journal" duplicate$ item.check
  ",~" * format.vol.num.pages * output
}
```

Comment: @Tino: since my response seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count.