# Bibliography style unsrt.bst - volume bold

Tags: bibtex, bold

I am using the `unsrt.bst` bibliography style. The only thing I need to change is the volume into bold.

I found this post [Harvard agsm bibliography style no comma and bold volume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47583/harvard-agsm-bibliography-style-no-comma-and-bold-volume) and I changed

```
{ volume field.or.null

to

{ volume embolden field.or.null
```

in function

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
```

I saved the file under `myunsrt.bst`, refreshed the FNDB but the volume of the articles is still not bold.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Did you changed the `bibliographystyle` inside your tex file?

Comment: I opened the unsrt.bst with notepad+ changed the above mentioned and saved the file as myunsrt.bst.

Comment: You have to use `\bibliographystyle{myunsrt}`.

Comment: That is what is written in my tex-file. But the changes i did i made with notepad+. How should i change the code of the unsrt.bst with "\bibliographystyle{myunsrt}"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're encountering is that whereas the file `agsm.bst` provides the function `embolden`, the file `unsrt.bst` -- and hence your copy of this file, `myunsrt.bst` -- does *not*. (If you look closely at the `.blg` file, you'll probably find some non-fatal complaints about an unknown function named "embolden"...)

Not to worry: Just add the following function to your file `myunsrt.bst` -- somewhere near the top, say near the function "output" -- and you should be in business:

```
FUNCTION {embolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

**Addendum**: The file `unsrt.bst` is one of the original bibtex style files, i.e., it's been around for more than 20 years. If there's any chance that some of the entries in your `.bib` file(s) will contain fields such as `url`, `isbn`, `issn`, `doi`, and `eid`, you should really contemplate using the file `unsrtnat.bst` -- distributed with the `natbib` package -- instead of `unsrt.bst`. Its formatting is pretty much identical to that of `unsrt`, but it knows what to do with these additional types of fields. Of course, if you still want those journal volume numbers printed in bold, you'll again have to add the function `embolden`, change the line of code in the function `format.vol.num.pages`, and save the file under a new name, say, `myunsrtnat.bst`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/ftp/nature.bst

It looks like the fix (without needing to define a new function) is as follows:

inside:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
```

Change the line:

```
{ volume field.or.null
```

To:

```
{ "{ \bf " volume "}" * * field.or.null
```