# Where is .bst file

Tags: biblatex, bold

I am new to this, so if I have left out any information please just let me know, I will fill it in if I can.

I am trying to get bold volume numbers in my bibliography, and it seems that the solution is to edit the .bst file ([Harvard agsm bibliography style no comma and bold volume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47583/harvard-agsm-bibliography-style-no-comma-and-bold-volume) and [How to edit a .bst file to get bold volume number in case of articles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286680/how-to-edit-a-bst-file-to-get-bold-volume-number-in-case-of-articles) for example).

However, I can't find the .bst file! It appears that it should be in C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\numeric.bst ([Add bst file with LaTeX / MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255664/add-bst-file-with-latex-miktex)) or something similar, but there are no MiKTeX program files! I know that sounds crazy.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TexMaker on Windows 7.

Here is a basic example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none,natbib=true,firstinits=true,uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional)
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
Example text with citation \citep{Liu14}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the bibliography file content:

```
@article{Liu14,
    Author = {F. Liu and L. Chen and B. Tang and Y. Hu and Q. Lin and L. Lei},
    Journal = {Lighting Res. Technol.},
    Numpages = {9},
    Pages = {567--575},
    Title = {{A discontinuous surface reflector for
high-power integrated LEDs}},
    Volume = {46},
    Number = {},
    doi = {},
    Year = {2014}
}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Text]

[image: Bibliography]

Comment: .bst files are for BibTeX. You are using BibLaTeX, which is *very* different. For BibLaTeX there should be an option that does this. No .bst trickery needed :)

Comment: You are almost there, you want `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}`.

Comment: You are using biblatex, it doesn't use bst-files. All references to them are irrelevant for you.

Comment: Thank you all! I was so confused! @moewe that sorted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` does not use `.bst` files for its bibliography styles. `.bst` files are an integral part of creating bibliographies with BibTeX. But `biblatex` uses a different language and different files (`.bbx`, `.cbx`) for bibliography and citation styles. So if you are using `biblatex` editing `.bst` files is a thing of the past. <sub><sub>There is actually one `.bst` file that belongs to `biblatex`: `biblatex.bst`, but you should never have to edit that file and it has no influence on the style of the output. If you recall that the `.bst` files essentially tell `bibtex` how to produce the `.bbl` file, the discussion about the differences between `.bbl`s for `biblatex` and BibTeX that I explained in an answer to [Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864) today might be of interest, so I might as well link it here.</sub></sub>

You only need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

the `\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}` was almost there. But because the standard styles have a type-specific formatting for `volume`, you need to overwrite the type-specific format using the optional argument - if you don't use the optional argument you only overwrite the generic format. Another possible way to make the volume bold would have been a starred `\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}` which would have influenced all types with undesirable consequences.

Uncomment each of the `volume` lines in the example below to see their effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, natbib=true, giveninits=true, uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional)
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}% <- good, changes only @article and @periodical
%\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}% <- doubly bad, doesn't help and destroys the format for e.g. @book
%\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}% <- bad, destroys the format for e.g. @book

\begin{document}
\citep{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]